# Which is faster: Sum(Case When) Or Group By/Count(*)?

Tags: sql, count, sum

I can write

```
Select 
Sum(Case When Resposta.Tecla = 1 Then 1 Else 0 End) Valor1,
Sum(Case When Resposta.Tecla = 2 Then 1 Else 0 End) Valor2,
Sum(Case When Resposta.Tecla = 3 Then 1 Else 0 End) Valor3,
Sum(Case When Resposta.Tecla = 4 Then 1 Else 0 End) Valor4,
Sum(Case When Resposta.Tecla = 5 Then 1 Else 0 End) Valor5
From Resposta
```

Or

```
Select 
    Count(*)
From Resposta Group By Tecla
```

I tried this over a large number of rows and it seems like taking the same time.

Anyone can confirm this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the Group By is better because there are no specific treatments.
It can be optimized by the database engine.
I think the results may depend on the database engine you use.
Maybe the one you are using optimizes the first query anderstanding it is like a group by !

You can try the "explain / explain plan" command to see how the engine is computing your querys but with my Microsoft SQL Server 2008, I just can see a swap between 2 operations ("Compute scalar" and "agregate").

I tried such queries on a database table :

- SQL Server 2k8
- 163000 rows in the table
- 12 cathegories (Valor1 -> Valor12)

the results are quite differents :

- Group By : 2seconds
- Case When : 6seconds !

So My choice is "Group By".
Another benefit is the query is simplyer to write !

Answer (score 3):

What the DB does internally with the second query is practically the same as what you explicitly tell it to do with the first. There should be no difference in the execution plan and thus in the time the query takes. Taking this into account, clearly using the second query is better:

- it's much more flexible, when there are more values of `Tecla` you
  don't need to change your query
- it's easier to understand. If you have a lot of values for `Tecla`
  it'll be harder to read the first query and realize it just counts
  distinct values
- it's smaller - you're sending less information to the DB server and it will probably parse the query faster, which is the only performance difference I see in this queries. This    makes a difference, albeit small

Answer (score 2):

Either one is going to have to read all rows from `Resposta`, so for any reasonably sized table, I'd expect the I/O cost to dominate - giving approximately the same overall runtime.

I'd generally use:

```
Select
    Tecla,
    Count(*)
From Resposta
Group By Tecla
```

If there's a reasonable chance that the range of `Tecla` values will change in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion `GROUP BY` statement will always be faster than `SUM(CASE WHEN ...)` because in your example for `SUM ...` there would be 5 different calculations while when using `GROUP BY`, DB will simply sort and calculate.

Imagine, you have a bag with different coins and you need to know, how much of earch type of coins do you have. You can do it this ways:

- The `SUM(CASE WHEN ...)` way would be to compare each coin with predefined sample coins and    do the math for each sample (add 1 or 0);
- The `GROUP BY` way would be to sort coins by their types and then count earch group.

Which method would you prefer?

Answer (score 0):

To fairly compete with `count(*)`, Your first SQL should probably be:

```
Select 
Sum(Case When Resposta.Tecla >= 1 AND Resposta.Tecla <=5 Then 1 Else 0 End) Valor
From Resposta
```

And to answer your question, I'm not noticing a difference at all in speed between `SUM CASE WHEN` and `COUNT`.  I'm querying over 250,000 rows in POSTGRESQL.